# Optimization solvers change their performance in different programming languages?

Tags: optimization, solver

I would like to know if any optimization solver depends on the language that it's being implemented.

For example, calling the same version of CPLEX using C and using MATLAB should have different performances?

I've heard the answer is "yes" because each language prepares the optimization problem for the solver in different ways.

But I also have heard the "no" answer; people say that the solver is implemented in C whatever the language we're using to call it, so the performance is the same.

Who should I listen to, guys?

Answer (score 0):

For MIP solvers like Cplex and Gurobi, the short answer is '**no**' when it comes down to the performance regarding solving the problem. Both are written in C and each API written in another language like Python, Matlab, Julia etc. is just *wrapping* the C API.

However, the language can make a difference when it comes down to the time needed to build the mathematical model. This is particularly noticeable with relatively large problems.

Comment: Makes sense, bro. Thanks!